# How to pass the value of variable when next page loads in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable named collar whose value is either red or green. It is used for random order as on or off. But in next page,it wont retain its previous value. How to do that. I am beginner in JavaScript.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this answer useful.[Maintaing state in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34966825/6521550). You may use `cookies` to store the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cookies or pass it to a server side back end using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), [sessionStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770887/passing-value-to-js-function-through-url-on-window-load), [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), or query parameters.

Please take a look at these similar questions:

- [How to get JS variable to retain value after page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh)
- [javascript passing variables to the next page (without php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964398/javascript-passing-variables-to-the-next-page-without-php)
- [Global Variable usage on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload)
- [pass variable between php and javascript without load page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422295/pass-variable-between-php-and-javascript-without-load-page)
- [Passing variable when opening another html page using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29364121/passing-variable-when-opening-another-html-page-using-javascript)
- [Pass a variable to new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016449/pass-a-variable-to-new-page)
- [Maintaining state in javascript through html class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966743/maintaining-state-in-javascript-through-html-class/34966825#34966825)
- [Passing value to JS function through URL on window load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770887/passing-value-to-js-function-through-url-on-window-load)

Answer (score 0):

All of the variables in Javascript only valid in an html page.
- When coming the another page, You may named same variable name but actually different variable.
- When the page is reloaded, the variable value is reset, current value is not kept.

If you really need previous value to be passed through next page, you can rely on server or local storage to keep the value and to be retrieve by the next page.